# Boost.type erasure. Move only type

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, type-erasure

I am trying to use a move-only type in boost.type erasure library:

```
using any_move_only_object = boost::type_erasure::any<boost::mpl::vector<
   //my interface,
   //How can I say I want move only types here?>>
```

I cannot figure out how to make move-only types usable with the libraries and I couldn't find any documentation.

Is it even possible?

Regards

Comment: This is not possible ([boost/type_erasure/detail/storage.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/type_erasure/detail/storage.hpp) defines `storage` without any non-const or moving constructors, and there do not seem to be any workarounds in the code). I would consider this a bug/misfeature, that should be reported/discussed on the [Boost.Dev](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel) mailing list.

Comment: Bear in mind that Boost libraries tend to be C++03 compatible, which might explain the (partial?) lack of support for move-semantics

Comment: Well, writing my own is not going to be the best solution, I think I will have to revert to classic OO inheritance. But it would be really nice to have this feature, would help a lot in my current code. Another way is to make things copyable, but I think it makes not much sense in my case, actually. Could make misuse more likely.

Comment: @Mankarse: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as [boost/type_erasure/detail/storage.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/type_erasure/detail/storage.hpp) defines `storage` without any non-const or moving constructors, and there do not seem to be any workarounds in the code.

I would consider this a bug/misfeature, that should be reported/discussed on the [Boost.Dev](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel) mailing list